# MySQL database stored in different location

Tags: mysql, database

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 and I have already installed MySQL (default install using apt). I'd like to set up a database on an external USB harddrive, as it has a large amount of free storage.

How can  I achieve this? I have no idea where to begin!

Comment: USB 2.0 will be slow, MySQL will crash if the disk is not connected, hopefully ext. disk would not be formatted with FAT/NTFS fs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet if you want 2 separate database storage areas is to run 2 separate instances of MySQL with 2 separate configurations.

[Here](http://www.ducea.com/2009/01/19/running-multiple-instances-of-mysql-on-the-same-machine/)'s a good tutorial how to do it.